# How do I check for string duplicates in a text file with PHP?

Tags: php

If there are 2 lines with the same string in a text file, how do I make PHP delete every but one line?
I'm getting an error when I try this:

```
$file = fopen("textfile.txt", "r") or die("CANNOT FIND FILE. ABORTING");
if(strpos($file, $crypt) !== false) {
    fclose($file);
} else {
    $filet = fopen("textfile.txt", "a") or die("CANNOT FIND FILE. ABORTING");
    fwrite($filet, $crypt);
    fwrite($filet, "\n");
    fclose($filet);
}
```

But I get an error:

> Warning: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in D:\xampp\htdocs\validing.php on line 19

I don't know how to fix it. I've been looking on the internet, but I'm basically blind or there are no solutions.
Any help very appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Do you need to encrypt each of the lines as a separate string so trying to avoid duplicate content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Warning: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in D:\xampp\htdocs\validing.php on line 19

This is because you are directly passing the path to the `strpos()` function without get the contents of the file

**Steps**

**1:** Initially get the contents of the file by `file_get_contents()`;

**2:** And then explode it at the desired position to get the contents in array and then you 
   can pass the strings to the `strpos()` function from an array.

Comment: @Kalsep if it helped you can you please accept it as answer.